# Criteria API IN with ArrayList

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, criteria

Can Criteria use List in "IN" expression?

For example:

```
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        ids.add(1L);
        ids.add(2L);
        ids.add(3L);
```

I want to find all id with 1, 2, 3

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> userQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> userRoot = userQuery.from(User.class);
    userQuery.select(userRoot);
    userQuery.where(userRoot.get("id").in("1","2","3"));
```

How to use List instead of this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Expression.html#in-java.util.Collection-

Comment: `in(ids.toArray())`?

Comment: @мυѕτавєւмo `ids` is sufficient. There is another in() method taking a Collection as argument.

Comment: @JBNizet that's nice, I'm not familiar with the API, so I saw it would be helpful to convert the list to an array :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work, using only ids as parameter in 'ín' method

---

```
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    ids.add(1L);
    ids.add(2L);
    ids.add(3L);
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> userQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> userRoot = userQuery.from(User.class);
    userQuery.select(userRoot);
    userQuery.where(userRoot.get("id").in(ids));
```

Answer (score 1):

U can use `Predicate`

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> userQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> userRoot = userQuery.from(User.class);
Expression<String> userExpression = userRoot.get("id");
Predicate userPredicate = userExpression.in(ids);
userQuery.where(userPredicate );
```